# Code changed on Emails templates

Tags: magento2, sales-order, email-templates

I'm working on a website that is upgraded to `Magento2.4.4`, now getting errors on emails (missing customer and shipping details, etc). After testing found that changing variables like `customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()` into `customer_name=$order_data.customer_name` resolved the issue. I'm curious about which version the variables get changed to because the old code was working fine on the old version. So any details about the variables/issue related shared will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Adobe Commerce and Magento Open Source **2.3.4**, custom email templates are only allowed to use scalar values for variable data. Direct calls to methods are no longer allowed. To be more specific, methods can no longer be called from variables from either the `var` directive or when used as parameters. For example `{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}` or `{{something myVar=$obj.method()}}` will fail to resolve.

You can read more about that change in the official document https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/templates/email-migration/#changes-to-the-custom-email-template-workflow

Comment: thanks for the reference.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman You're welcome.